# uiimage.size, .CGColor, uicolor.CGColor thread safety in ios3

Tags: iphone, thread-safety, uiimage

Under ios3(3.1.2 and up), is the access of the following properties thread safe?

1. uiImage.size
2. uiImage.CGColor -- edit: oops this should be uiImage.CGImage
3. uiColor.CGColor

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those properties are all declared as `nonatomic`, which means they have no multithreaded-access safeguards in place.  You are, of course, welcome to access these properties on multiple threads, but you do so at your own peril.

---

Here's the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW28) about this.  If the properties were declared without `nonatomic`, then a lock would be used during the getting and setting of the value, guaranteeing that only one thread was accessing the value at a single time.  As you might expect, there's a slight performance penalty to this.  When a property is declared as `nonatomic`, it simply means that *no lock is used*.  You're welcome to get and set the property value from any thread you like.  However, as with *any* multithreaded value access, there's the possibility of thread contention over that property, which could (in some circumstances) lead to undefined behavior.

*Usually*, however, you don't have to worry about this too much.  This really only applies to properties whose values can be *set* from multiple threads.  The properties you're interested in (`UIImage.size`, `UIImage.CGImage`, `UIColor.CGColor`) are all declared as `readonly`, which means that there's really nothing to worry about when accessing those values from multiple threads, simultaneously or otherwise.

Comment: wow, thanks, didn't know I could interpret "nonatomic" like that.  Is there a way to get UIImage's size thread safe way then?

Comment: is it ok to access those properties from non-main thread as long as there are single thread accessing it? or is it outright wrong to access them from non-main thread?